# What's the difference between interpreter and .ml file?

Tags: ocaml, interpreter

I am new to Ocaml and also using interpreter. I've made a fine code that works well but the problem is that the behavior of same code differs by interpreter and .ml file. For example I made a module and used the functions there to debug. However if I write

```
let (n, queue) = IntListQ.deQ(IntListQ.enQ(IntListQ.enQ(IntListQ.emptyQ, [1;2;3]), [4;5])) in
        (n, queue)
```

in the .ml file it doesn't compile and prints Syntax error. On the other hand, if I write the expression in the interpreter by starting ocaml -init {filename}.ml it works. So what is the problem? Why does the same expression behave different in .ml file and interpreter?

to give details the whole code looks like this

```
type heap = EMPTY of rank | NODE of rank * value * heap * heap
and rank =int
and value=int

exception EmptyHeap

let rank : heap -> rank = fun i ->
    match i with
    | EMPTY _ -> -1
    | NODE (r, _, _ ,_) -> r

(****print heap expression****)

module type Queue =  
    sig
        type element
        type queue
        exception EMPTY_Q
        val emptyQ: queue
        val enQ: queue * element -> queue
        val deQ: queue -> element * queue   
        val isempty : queue -> bool
    end

module IntListQ  = 
    struct
        type element = heap
        type queue = heap list * heap list(*element list??*)
        exception EMPTY_Q

        let emptyQ : heap list * heap list = ([],[])

        let enQ: (heap list * heap  list) * heap ->  heap  list * heap  list = fun (que , ele)->
            let (first, second) = que in
            let new_second = List.append second (List.rev first) in
            (ele::[] ,new_second)

        let deQ: (heap  list * heap  list) -> heap * (heap list * heap  list) = fun que ->
        match que with
        | ([], []) -> raise EMPTY_Q
        | _ ->
            let (first, second) = que in
            let new_second = List.append second (List.rev first) in
            let out = List.hd new_second in
            (out, ([],List.tl new_second))

        let isemtpy: heap list * heap list -> bool = fun i ->
            match i with
            | ([], []) -> true
            | _ -> false
    end

let printhpst : heap -> unit = fun x ->
    let startq = ref IntListQ.emptyQ    
    startq := IntListQ.enQ !startq (EMPTY -1)
    let tim = ref false in
        while  !tim do
            let n = startq.deQ
            printhp n;
            match n with
            | NODE (i, j, k, l) -> 
            begin
                startq := IntListQ.enQ !startq k
                startq := IntListQ.enQ !startq l
            end
            | EMPTY 0-> ()
            | EMPTY -1 -> startq := IntListQ.enQ !startq EMPTY -1

            tim := IntListQ.isempty startq
        done

let printhp : heap -> unit = fun hp ->
    match hp with
    |EMPTY  _ -> print_endline "EMPTY";
    |NODE (i, j, k, l) -> (print_endline ("( "^(string_of_int i)^" , "^(string_of_int j)^" , "^(string_of_int (rank k))^" , "^(string_of_int (rank l))^" )"););;

let findMin h = 
    (match h with
    | EMPTY _ -> raise EmptyHeap
    | (NODE(_,x,_,_)) -> x);;

let shake (x, lh, rh) = 
    print_endline "shake";
    if(rank lh) >= (rank rh)
    then NODE(rank rh+1, x, lh, rh)
    else NODE(rank lh+1, x, rh, lh)

let rec merge : heap * heap -> heap = fun (lh, rh)->
    match (lh, rh) with
    | ( EMPTY _ , EMPTY _ ) -> print_endline "merge: EMPTY Empty"; printhp lh; printhp rh; print_endline "_____________________";EMPTY 0
    | ( EMPTY _, NODE (i, j, k, l) )
    | (NODE (i, j, k, l), EMPTY _ ) -> print_endline "merge:NODE"; printhp lh; printhp rh; print_endline "_____________________"; NODE ( i, j, k, l )
    | (NODE _, NODE _ )->
        print_endline "merge:NODE NODE";
        printhp lh;
        printhp rh;
        print_endline "_____________________";
        let minlh = findMin lh in
        let minrh = findMin rh in

        if minlh<=minrh then 

            (print_endline "minlh<=minrh";
            print_endline "_____________________";
            let dellh = deleteMin lh in
            shake (minlh, dellh, rh))

        else
            (print_endline "minlh>minrh";
            print_endline "_____________________";
            let delrh= deleteMin rh in
            shake (minrh, delrh, lh))

and insert : rank*heap -> heap = fun (x, h )->
    merge(h, NODE( 0, x, EMPTY 0, EMPTY 0))

and deleteMin h = 
    print_endline "deleteMin";
    printhp h;
    print_endline "_____________________";
    match h with
    | EMPTY _ -> raise EmptyHeap
    | NODE(_, x , lh, rh) -> merge (lh, rh)

(* try basic 
  let heap1 = NODE(0, 2, EMPTY, EMPTY) in
  let heap2 = NODE(0, 3, EMPTY, EMPTY) in
  findMin(merge (heap1, heap2));;
   *)
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what is in `filename.ml`: your code extract is valid by itself. Did you use a REPL/interpreter directive?

Answer (score 1):

To get a useful answer you need to give more details, including the definition of IntListQ.

If the interpreter (OCaml toplevel) and the compiler (ocamlc/ocamlopt) disagreed on the language, this would probably have been noticed by now.

The most common reason for unexpected behavior of the interpreter is that there were some existing definitions in the interpreter when you loaded your file. If you try again starting the interpreter up from scratch for the test, you might see more consistent behavior.